# On Error go to the next desired operation instead of next line

Tags: vb.net, excel, error-handling

How can I make this code

```
For Each wb In wbC
        If InStr(wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("keywords").value(), "MyApplicationSet") = 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
        End If

        Call OverTimeSave(wb)
    Next
```

so when the current workbook is not part of the system - it skips that one workbook (without saving it) and iterates to the next workbook? 
Is that code correct, because I am not sure the `On Error Resume Next` will do the work here, as I read, it will just go to the next statement, which means it will call the save function on the particular workbook, which is not part of my system.

I want it like: if there's error - do nothing and iterate to the next workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to simply change the if-condition to add every workbook that's part of the system

```
For Each wb In wbC
        If InStr(wb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("keywords").value(), "MyApplicationSet") <> 0 Then
            Call OverTimeSave(wb)
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that, though it's simple! :D

Just, that in VB the "not equal" is `<>`, but not `!=`